# stop thread listening for TcpClient from another thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently making client/server app in c# forms. The window has Log(text area), command line(text area) and one button. I have problem with closing server(another thread) while it's running.

```
    void Server_Thread_Main(object arg)
    {
        TcpClient client;
        Output.Insert_to_LOG_Window("Server initialized at IP: " + IP_ADDR + ":" + PORT);
        while (true)
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            clients.Add(new C_Client(client, Output, client_ID_iter++));

            clients[clients.Count - 1].Start();
        }




    }
```

also I have class for processing commands entered to command line. It's called Task_Menager. Each command is processed by new thread For proccesing command it has this function

```
    void Server_Task_CMD(optargs args)
    {
        bool if_start = false;

        foreach(argument arg in args)
        {
            switch (arg.Option)
            {
                case "-stop":
                    Output.server.Stop_Server(); //<- stopping server
                    break;
                case "-start":
                    if_start = true;
                    break;
                case "-IP":
                    Output.server.Set_Server_IP(arg.Value);
                    break;
                case "-PORT":
                    Output.server.Set_Server_PORT(arg.Value);
                    break;
                case "-IPP":
                    if (arg.Value.Contains(':') == true)
                        Output.server.Set_Server_Params(arg.Value);
                    else
                        Output.Insert_to_COMMAND_Log("This " + arg.Value + " isn't valid IP:PORT notation!");
                    break;
                case "-V":
                case "-VIEW":
                    Output.server.Display_IP_PORT();
                    break;
                default:
                    Output.Insert_to_COMMAND_Log("Not known command: " + arg.Option + " !");
                    break;



            }
            if(if_start==true)
                Output.server.Initialize_Server();

        }
    }
```

and this function is

```
    public void Stop_Server()
    {
        if (server_thread.IsAlive == true)
        {
            Output.Insert_to_LOG_Window("Stopping server...");
            server_thread.Interrupt();
            if (!server_thread.Join(2000))
            {
                server_thread.Abort();
            }
            Output.Insert_to_COMMAND_Log("Server has been stopped!!!");
        }
        else
            Output.Insert_to_LOG_Window("Server isn't running right now!");



    }
```

And the problem is I don't know why the server thread isn't stopping.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to close to the thread. Currently your thread is probably stuck on the `listener.AcceptTcpClient`

You should first close the listener with `listener.Stop();`
Second, you have to close all your clients sockets.
And third, you shouldn't call `thread.Abort` unless there's absolutely no other way.

So your `Stop_Server` should look more like this:

```
public void Stop_Server()
{
    listener.Stop();
    server_thread.Join();
    Output.Insert_to_COMMAND_Log("Server has been stopped!!!");
}
```

And in you thread method wrap the `while (true)` with `try-catch(SocketException)`

Learn more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thank you, it helped :) I knew that it was stopping on  'client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();', but didn't know that I can stop it from another thread.